# Resolve Views through IoC or MEF instead of using SelectedAssemblies() method

Tags: mvvm, mef, ioc-container, caliburn.micro

I use Caliburn.Micro with Spring.net instead of the default simple IoC. My custom Bootstrapper (derrived from Caliburn's BootstrapperBase) is working and I can define the ViewModels within Spring.net. But the the Views are still resolved by reflection (name convention) from the execution assembly. I used the following method of the Bootstrapper to add Assemblies for resolving the Views for the ViewModels.

```
    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        // hmm, want to change the way how the view is resolved... how to do this?
        // ... use IoC or MEF for this task instead?
        return new[]
                   {
                       // don't want to add every dll here
                       this.GetType().Assembly,
                       Assembly.Load("MyViewModels.Assembly") 
                   };
    }
```

How to change the behaviour of resolving views and using IoC or MEF for this task?
The Problem is that the Bootstrapper has no virtual method to override which resolves a requested view. What is the starting point to change this behaviour? I thought there must exist something like

```
protected virtual Control ResolveViewForModel(Type modelType) {...}
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't know caliburn.micro so this might be wrong.

Looking at the [`ViewLocator`](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ViewLocator.cs) method `LocateTypeForModelType` it seems that it asks the `AssemblySource` for available types which should be checked against the [View-naming conventions](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View/ViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation).

Since all of the above are static classes I suspect there is no way to inherit and override that behaviour. Since they are static, one could just add assemblies to the public observable dictionary - which feels a little bit of a hack and `SelectAssemblies` seems like the proper way.

However, it seems to me that since there are conventions for resolving `Views` and `ViewModels` one could do the same for assemblies which brings us to the question: how do you decide which assemblies to scan for `ViewModels`/`Views`. 
That strategy can be built into the `SelectAssemblies` method.

If you want to change how caliburn.micro finds the right views in those assemblies, effectively changing/adding to the [exisiting](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View/ViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation) conventions, [there is an explanation in their wiki](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Handling%20Custom%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation).

To finally answer your question: "*Resolve Views through IoC or MEF instead of using SelectedAssemblies() method*": Imo this kind of defeats the philosophy of Caliburn.Micro:

Caliburn.Micro uses conventions to resolve views from given assemblies - trying to use an IoC container instead of a name / namespace based convention contradicts that approach.